# Prove that the property of being isolated is a topological property

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism and $A \subset X$ such that $A \cap A'= \emptyset$ prove that $f[A] \cap (f[A])'= \emptyset$ where $A'$ is the derived set  of $A$ and $(f[A])'$ is the derived set of $f[A]$
Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Try to show that if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f[A'] = (f[A])'$.

Comment: if $a \in A'$ then since f is a homeomorphism $f(a) \in (f[A])'$ thus $f[A']=(f[A])'$ Is it correct?

Comment: if f is a homeomorphism then it is correct to write $f[A \cap A']=f[A] \cap f[A']$?

Comment: If $f$ is injective then you have $f[S\cap T] = f[S] \cap f[T]$ for all subsets $S,T$ of $X$. In particular, that holds for bijections, and hence homeomorphisms.